# Проблема с функцией CopyFile()

Tags: c++

Пишу код, который предусматривает копирование файла. Решил пока использовать функцию CopyFile(...).

Собственно проблема, когда использую что-то вроде этого:

```
void copy_files(List<Photo> &list, const string &dir)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.Get_Size(); i++)
    {
        string old_name = dir + list[i].Get_name();
        string new_name = dir + NEW_DIRECTION + to_string(i) + JPG;

        CopyFile(old_name.c_str(), "D://0.jpg", false);
    }
}
```

Всё работает, правда не так как хочется. Файл копируется, но каждый цикл просто перезаписывает новый файл в константное название, что, конечно, не дело.
Хочется, чтобы работало вот это:

```
void copy_files(List<Photo> &list, const string &dir)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.Get_Size(); i++)
    {
        string old_name = dir + list[i].Get_name();
        string new_name = dir + NEW_DIRECTION + to_string(i) + JPG;

        CopyFile(old_name.c_str(), new_name.c_str(), false);
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае файл по указанному адресу не создаётся. Пробовал так же писать новый путь константой "D:\new\0.jpg", так же не давало результатов. Видимо, что-то не понимаю в работе функции.

на всякий:

```
#define NEW_DIRECTION "PhotoSorting_result\\"
#define JPG ".jpg"
```

код пишу в MS_VS_2017
язык С++

Comment: Вывод old_name.c_str() и new_name.c_str() непосредственно перед CopyFile определенно должен помочь вам разобраться в чем проблема.

Comment: А целевая папка-то вообще существует? А права на запись в нее есть?

Comment: В выводе в консоль тоже, что и видел в отладчике, то есть то, что и нужно было, тут без проблем.
а вот на счёт сущевствовнания  папки - это в точку. Огромное спасибо)

Comment: Следует проверить значение, которое возвращает `CopyFile` и вызвать `GetLastError` для получения кода ошибки. Кроме того, следует явно использовать `CopyFileW`.